# El title me aparece en el body

Tags: html, html5

Tengo el siguiente código:

```css
*{  background: gray;
 display: block;
}
body {
 text-align: center;
}
#reproducir {
 width: 720px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 padding: 5px; 
 background: #999;
 border: 1px solid #666;
 border-radius: 5px
 background: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Programando Reproductor</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Reproductor.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Reproductor.css">
</head>
<body>
 <section id="reproducir">
  <video id="video" width= "720" height= "400" src="musica.mp4" controls loop>
  </video>
  <nav>
   <div id="botones">
    <button id="reproducir" type="button" >
     Reproducir
    </button>
   </div>
   <div id="barra">
    <div id="progreso"></div>
   </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>  
  </nav>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Y, cómo se ve en la captura siguiente, el título de la página me aparece en el cuerpo de la página:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por qué ocurre eso y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Todo lo que engoble la cabecera de un documento HTML se debe de establecer dentro de la etiqueta **<head>...</head>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La cabecera con la meta información de la página es `head` y no `header`. Es importante diferenciar las dos.

- [`head`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/head) “provee información general (metadatos) acerca del documento, incluyendo su título y enlaces a scripts y hojas de estilos.”
- [`header`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/header) “representa un grupo de ayudas introductorias o de navegación. Puede contener algunos elementos de encabezado, pero también otros elementos como un logo, una sección que aglutine secciones de encabezados, una formulario de búsqueda o cosas parecidas.”

En tu código pones `header` (que es una sección visible) donde debería ser `head` (que es una sección oculta). Cambia eso y el problema se solucionará.

Comment: Saludos y gracias por su respuesta y edición, lo siento fue mi primer post. Edite el header por head , y aun me sigue apareciendo el titulo en el body.

Comment: @Frnk no hace falta que digas “lo siento”. La pregunta es buena para el sitio, y para ser tu primera pregunta tampoco está tan mal. Quizás le faltaba un poco de detalle, pero entre todos la editamos para que se vea algo mejor. La cuestión es ayudarse y aprender. Las siguientes serán mejores :)

Comment: Como añadido a lo que ha dicho @AlvaroMontoro quita de tu CSS el `display: block` que tienes en la segunda linea, con eso debería dejar de verse el `<title>` en tu página :).

Comment: @Ferni una recomendacion para poder tener todo el codigo el display block ? , o tengo que llamar a uno por uno separandolos de coma , cual seria lo adecuado cuando tengo muchos tag que quiero volver bloques.

Comment: En vez de ponérselo a la etiqueta * pónselo a la etiqueta `body`